# xmonad `tags <- asks (workspaces . config)` magic -- how do I parse that?

Tags: haskell, monads, xmonad

I'm poking the `XMonad.Actions.WindowMenu` module from `xmonad-contrib`, trying to make it configurable.

And I have hard time understanding the following bit:

In the [original code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/src/XMonad.Actions.WindowMenu.html#windowMenu) is a construct like:

```hs
windowMenu :: X ()
windowMenu = withFocused $ \w -> do
    tags <- asks (workspaces . config)
    -- ...
```

What is the best way to go about understanding what's going on there? In other words, in what context is the whole `tags <- asks (workspaces . config)` evaluated?

The reason I'm asking is that when I try to refactor this in a different function:

```hs
defaultActs :: [(String, X ())]
defaultActs = do
    tags <- asks (workspaces . config)
    [ ("A: " ++ tag, return ()) | tag <- tags]
```

it blows up with an error:

```
    • No instance for (MonadReader XConf [])
        arising from a use of ‘asks’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: tags <- asks (workspaces . 
      In the expression:
        do tags <- asks (workspaces . config)
           [("A: " ++ tag, return ()) | tag <- tags]
      In an equation for ‘defaultActs’:
          defaultActs
            = do tags <- asks (workspaces . config)
                 [("A: " ++ tag, return ()) | tag <- tags]
```

Edited to add:

I understand the types of that statement:

```
ghci> :t asks (workspaces . config)
asks (workspaces . config) :: MonadReader XConf m => m [String]
ghci> :t withFocused
withFocused :: (Window -> X ()) -> X ()
```

but the reason it breaks is (still) a mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing is to just have both `windowMenu` and `defaultActions` operate in the `X` monad, which already has the appropriate `MonadReader` instance. So:

```
defaultActions :: X [(String, X ())]
defaultActions = do
    tags <- asks (workspaces . config)
    return ([ ("Cancel menu", return ())
            , ("Close"      , kill)
            , ("Maximize"   , withFocused $ \w -> sendMessage $ maximizeRestore w)
            , ("Minimize"   , withFocused $ \w -> minimizeWindow w)
            ] ++
            [ ("Move to " ++ tag, windows $ W.shift tag) | tag <- tags ])

windowMenu :: X ()
windowMenu = withFocused $ \w -> do
    acts <- defaultActions
    Rectangle x y wh ht <- getSize w
    Rectangle sx sy swh sht <- gets $ screenRect . W.screenDetail . W.current . windowset
    let originFractX = (fi x - fi sx + fi wh / 2) / fi swh
        originFractY = (fi y - fi sy + fi ht / 2) / fi sht
        gsConfig = (buildDefaultGSConfig colorizer)
                    { gs_originFractX = originFractX
                    , gs_originFractY = originFractY }
    runSelectedAction gsConfig acts
```

No need for the shenanigans in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61013887/1177128) of making `windowMenu'` be a parameterized higher-order function. If you really want to make a `windowMenu'` that lets you parameterize on the list of actions, do that directly:

```
windowMenu' :: [(String, X ())] -> X ()
windowMenu' acts = withFocused $ \w -> do
    Rectangle x y wh ht <- getSize w
    Rectangle sx sy swh sht <- gets $ screenRect . W.screenDetail . W.current . windowset
    let originFractX = (fi x - fi sx + fi wh / 2) / fi swh
        originFractY = (fi y - fi sy + fi ht / 2) / fi sht
        gsConfig = (buildDefaultGSConfig colorizer)
                    { gs_originFractX = originFractX
                    , gs_originFractY = originFractY }
    runSelectedAction gsConfig acts
```

In such a world, you can run `defaultActions` and pass its result to `windowMenu'` with `(>>=)` (or more `do` notation):

```
windowMenu :: X ()
windowMenu = defaultActions >>= windowMenu'
-- OR
windowMenu = do
    acts <- defaultActions
    windowMenu' acts
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting a comment:

> Yes, `windowMenu` has `X ()` as a type, and my `defaultActs` goes for a different type. What I don't understand is how does running the lambda through `withFocused` grant it "access" to some extra context.

You can use `asks` to retrieve configuration fields in that way because there is a `MonadReader XConf X` instance for [the `X` monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.15/docs/XMonad-Core.html#t:X). `MonadReader` is typically used to provide this kind of access to configuration.

---

> The reason I'm asking is that when I try to refactor this in a different function:
>
> ```
> defaultActs :: [(String, X ())]
>     defaultActs = do
>     tags <- asks (workspaces . config)
>     [ ("A: " ++ tag, return ()) | tag <- tags]
> ```

Looking at your definition, I suspect you intend `defaultActs` to be a modified list of workspace tags. That being so, what you want is probably this:

```
defaultActs :: X [String]
defaultActs = do
    tags <- asks (workspaces . config)
    return [ "A: " ++ tag | tag <- tags]
```

That is, obtain the tags from the configuration, produce a modified list, and return it in the context of the `X` monad.

Comment: Thanks, this was a nudge in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61013887/1177128.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to [duplode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002018/1177128) I was able to figure it out:

```hs
defaultActions :: XConf -> [(String, X ())]
defaultActions = do
    tags <- asks (workspaces . config)
    return ([ ("Cancel menu", return ())
            , ("Close"      , kill)
            , ("Maximize"   , withFocused $ \w -> sendMessage $ maximizeRestore w)
            , ("Minimize"   , withFocused $ \w -> minimizeWindow w)
            ] ++
            [ ("Move to " ++ tag, windows $ W.shift tag) | tag <- tags ])

windowMenu' :: (XConf -> [(String, X ())]) -> X ()
windowMenu' actions = withFocused $ \w -> do
    acts <- asks actions
    Rectangle x y wh ht <- getSize w
    Rectangle sx sy swh sht <- gets $ screenRect . W.screenDetail . W.current . windowset
    let originFractX = (fi x - fi sx + fi wh / 2) / fi swh
        originFractY = (fi y - fi sy + fi ht / 2) / fi sht
        gsConfig = (buildDefaultGSConfig colorizer)
                    { gs_originFractX = originFractX
                    , gs_originFractY = originFractY }
    runSelectedAction gsConfig acts

-- now it composes well, and I can pass in my own `actions` to `windowMenu`
windowMenu = windowMenu' defaultActions
```

Btw, I couldn't make it work as a `X [String]` type (not sure why), but the solution above seems to work well enough. Maybe it's not strictly the best (not sure about it), but it's taking me where I want to go.

Comment: (1) You couldn't make it work as `X [String]` because in your use case you really need to return those `X ()` actions alongside the tags, so that's okay. (2) Aside: you can write `defaultActions` like that, with `asks` and a do-block, because functions are also `MonadReader` instances. While `asks` on a `X` do-block (as in `windowMenu`) uses a `XConf` supplied by the X environment, in your `defaultActions` the `XConf` is actually a function argument that you'll pass to the function somewhere down the line; in any case, ỳou can use the same interface to access the `XConf`.

Comment: @duplode Re (1): yeah, I mean, I tried the whole `X ([(String, X ())])` and couldn't make *that* work. :-) Re (2): ok, now it makes  sense. I still find slightly confusing that I'm essentially passing `XConf` as a parameter implicitly and it seems as if the `asks (workspaces . config)` was "bound" to that. But I mean, it doesn't all have to make sense at once, I guess. :-) And I'm not passing it to the `defaultActions` implicitly, even. Because if you look at the 1st line of `windowMenu'`, `asks actions` is enough to magically pass in the correct stuff. I truly mean that: magic.

Comment: The magic is that `asks actions` takes the `XConf` from the X environment and passes it to `actions`. That works because `actions` is ultimately just a function (otherwise you wouldn't be able to pass it to `asks`).

Comment: If you don't like the `XConf` in your signature, you can simply take a `[String]` as input instead, representing the list of workspaces, and change `windowMenu` to `windowMenu = windowMenu' (workspaces . config $ defaultActions)`

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at any documentation, we know this much: this is in the context of do-notation for whatever type is needed by `withFocused`. It apparently takes a function as argument, and that function must return a monadic value of some type. The value of this do-notation block must have that same type. It certainly does *not* have the type `[(String, X ())]`. (Well, okay, it could, since `[a]` is a monad, but it seems rather unlikely that this is the type that `withFocused` would expect as result).

You can find out what type it has by looking through the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.15/docs/XMonad-Operations.html#v:withFocused):

```
withFocused :: (Window -> X ()) -> X ()
```

Since our do-notation is inside the return value of the lambda for the first parameter, it must have a type of `X ()`. Therefore,

```
asks (workspaces . config) :: X t
```

for some `t` which we could also know by looking up the type of `workspaces`. The `<-` binds that `t` value to the name `tags`, in the usual way that do-notation does.

Comment: Yes, `windowMenu` has `X ()` as a type, and my `defaultActs` goes for a different type. What I don't understand is how does running the lambda through `withFocused` grant it "access" to some extra context.

Maybe I just need to read a bit more about haskell in general, to avoid being so hopelessly lost.

Comment: @Wejn Running it through `withFocused` doesn't grant it access. Instead, it is the fact that `windowMenu` is running in the `X` monad that grants it access. (`withFocused` merely maintains that access -- it doesn't grant it anew.)

Comment: @DanielWagner hm, that's what I find slightly confusing: How come having a `do` block causes the code within to be somehow bound to something outside (if that's even what you mean by "is running in the `X` monad"). Anyway, I made it work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61013887/1177128, even if that's likely not the best way. Thanks for adding a piece to the puzzle!

Comment: @Wejn The `do` block doesn't cause it to be bound to something outside. The type signature/inferred type does.

Comment: @DanielWagner where I'm struggling is to imagine how `do` blocks get "bound" by type  signature. In the https://stackoverflow.com/a/61013887/1177128 I have signature `defaultActions :: XConf -> [(String, X ())]` and if I invoke that in `windowMenu'` as `acts <- asks actions` it magically gets bound the correct way. Why that works somewhat eludes me. I guess I'm missing some big picture concept.

Comment: @Wejn It's not surprising that you find the code in that answer confusing. It's written in a way that's a bit bonkers, using many levels of indirection; even a seasoned Haskell vet would have to spend a bit of careful thinking time to unravel exactly what's happening. It's probably not worth trying to understand -- there is much simpler code that achieves the same thing, and you should try to understand that instead.

Comment: @DanielWagner I like your answer. Btw, you assume that when I was refactoring the code to the "bonkers" form, I understood monads and `do` notation in depth. Well, I didn't. But I spent some time with https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell (and XMonad docs) and now I understand it somewhat better. Anyway, thanks for the answer with proper version. I was pretty sure I was holding it wrong: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/xmonad/2020-April/015367.html :-)